# mysql result to proper grouped json

Tags: php, json

I have a mysql query that returns a classification tree for small animals.

it goes type -> species -> breed -> variety

Basically I need:

```
json = {
    "anátidas": {
        "id": 1,
        "species": {
            "patos": {
                 "id": 1,
                 "breeds": {
                     "alto vuelo": {
                         "id":1,
                         "varieties": {
                             "otro": {
                                 "id":1
                             }
                         }
                     },{
                     "anade anteojillo": {
                         "id":2,
                         "varieties": {
                             "otro": {
                                 "id":2
                             }
                         }
                     },{
                     "anade bahamas": {
                         "id":3,
                         "varieties": {
                             "blanco": {
                                 "id":3
                             },{
                             "otro": {
                                 "id":4
                             }
                         }
                     },{
                     "anade friso": {
                         "id":4,
                         "varieties":{
                             "otro": {
                                 "id":5
                             }
                         }
                     }
                     [...]
                 }
             },
             {
            "ocas": {
                 "id": 2,
                 "breeds": {
                     "de cabeza barrada": {
                         "id":74,
                         "varieties": {
                             "otro": {
                                 "id":115
                             }
                         }
                     },{
                     "de egipto": {
                         "id":75,
                         "varieties": {
                             "otro": {
                                 "id":116
                             }
                         }
                     },{
                     "de los andes": {
                         "id":76,
                         "varieties": {
                             "otro": {
                                 "id":117
                             }
                         }
                     },
                     [...]
                 }
        }
    },"cobayas": {
        "id": 2,
        "species": {
            "cobaya": {
                 "id": 14,
                 "breeds": {
                     "alpaca": {
                         "id":1,
                         "varieties": {
                             "aguti canela": {
                                 "id":255
                             }
                         }
                     }
                     [...]
                 }
             }
             [...]
        }
    }
}
```

And the data I have is like this (but longer)

```
╔═════╦══════════╦═════╦═════════════════════╦═════╦══════════════════════════════╦══════╦═════════════════════════════════╗
║ tid ║   type   ║ sid ║       species       ║ bid ║            breed             ║ vid  ║             variety             ║
╠═════╬══════════╬═════╬═════════════════════╬═════╬══════════════════════════════╬══════╬═════════════════════════════════╣
║   1 ║ anátidas ║   1 ║ patos               ║   1 ║ alto vuelo                   ║    1 ║ otro                            ║
║   1 ║ anátidas ║   1 ║ patos               ║   2 ║ anade anteojillo             ║    2 ║ otro                            ║
║   1 ║ anátidas ║   1 ║ patos               ║   3 ║ anade bahamas                ║    3 ║ blanco                          ║
║   1 ║ anátidas ║   1 ║ patos               ║   3 ║ anade bahamas                ║    4 ║ otro                            ║
║   1 ║ anátidas ║   1 ║ patos               ║   4 ║ anade friso                  ║    5 ║ otro                            ║
║   1 ║ anátidas ║   1 ║ patos               ║  12 ║ carolina                     ║   14 ║ blanco                          ║
║   1 ║ anátidas ║   1 ║ patos               ║  12 ║ carolina                     ║   15 ║ carolina                        ║
║   1 ║ anátidas ║   1 ║ patos               ║  12 ║ carolina                     ║   16 ║ isabela                         ║
║   1 ║ anátidas ║   1 ║ patos               ║  16 ║ corredor indio               ║   31 ║ negro                           ║
║   1 ║ anátidas ║   1 ║ patos               ║  16 ║ corredor indio               ║   32 ║ otro                            ║
║   1 ║ anátidas ║   1 ║ patos               ║  16 ║ corredor indio               ║   33 ║ panache                         ║
║   1 ║ anátidas ║   1 ║ patos               ║  16 ║ corredor indio               ║   34 ║ plata                           ║
║   1 ║ anátidas ║   1 ║ patos               ║  16 ║ corredor indio               ║   35 ║ plata                           ║
║   1 ║ anátidas ║   2 ║ ocas                ║  74 ║ de cabeza barrada            ║  115 ║ otro                            ║
║   1 ║ anátidas ║   2 ║ ocas                ║  75 ║ de egipto                    ║  116 ║ otro                            ║
║   1 ║ anátidas ║   2 ║ ocas                ║  76 ║ de los andes                 ║  117 ║ otro                            ║
║   1 ║ anátidas ║   2 ║ ocas                ║  77 ║ emperador                    ║  118 ║ otro                            ║
║   1 ║ anátidas ║   2 ║ ocas                ║  78 ║ nival                        ║  119 ║ otro                            ║
║   2 ║ cobayas  ║  14 ║ cobaya              ║ 225 ║ alpaca                       ║  255 ║ aguti canela                    ║
║   2 ║ cobayas  ║  14 ║ cobaya              ║ 225 ║ alpaca                       ║  256 ║ aguti dorado                    ║
║   2 ║ cobayas  ║  14 ║ cobaya              ║ 225 ║ alpaca                       ║  257 ║ aguti gris                      ║
║   2 ║ cobayas  ║  14 ║ cobaya              ║ 225 ║ alpaca                       ║  258 ║ aguti plata                     ║
║   2 ║ cobayas  ║  14 ║ cobaya              ║ 225 ║ alpaca                       ║  259 ║ chocolate                       ║
║   2 ║ cobayas  ║  14 ║ cobaya              ║ 225 ║ alpaca                       ║  260 ║ negro                           ║
║   2 ║ cobayas  ║  14 ║ cobaya              ║ 225 ║ alpaca                       ║  261 ║ otro                            ║
║   2 ║ cobayas  ║  14 ║ cobaya              ║ 225 ║ alpaca                       ║  262 ║ tricolor                        ║
║   2 ║ cobayas  ║  14 ║ cobaya              ║ 226 ║ ch teddy                     ║  263 ║ otro                            ║
║   2 ║ cobayas  ║  14 ║ cobaya              ║ 227 ║ coronada                     ║  264 ║ aguti canela                    ║
║   2 ║ cobayas  ║  14 ║ cobaya              ║ 227 ║ coronada                     ║  265 ║ aguti dorado                    ║
║   3 ║ conejos  ║  15 ║ gigantes            ║ 237 ║ angora                       ║  282 ║ blanco                          ║
║   3 ║ conejos  ║  15 ║ gigantes            ║ 237 ║ angora                       ║  283 ║ gris                            ║
║   3 ║ conejos  ║  15 ║ gigantes            ║ 237 ║ angora                       ║  284 ║ negro                           ║
║   3 ║ conejos  ║  15 ║ gigantes            ║ 238 ║ angora aleman                ║  285 ║ azul                            ║
║   3 ║ conejos  ║  15 ║ gigantes            ║ 238 ║ angora aleman                ║  286 ║ blanco                          ║
║   3 ║ conejos  ║  15 ║ gigantes            ║ 238 ║ angora aleman                ║  287 ║ gris                            ║
╚═════╩══════════╩═════╩═════════════════════╩═════╩══════════════════════════════╩══════╩═════════════════════════════════╝
```

But I'm completely unable to see how to go from one to the other.

This is what I'm trying but it produces a plain json, not a proper structured one:

```
        $res = array();
    foreach ($stmt as $row) {
        array_push($res, $row);
    }
json_encode($res);
```

Comment: Ok. So what's your question / problem? Hopefully you have enough reputation on this site already that I don't need to suggest you to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm unable to create the json @ADyson

Comment: I think you can do a basic SELECT to get all the data you want, then do a foreach to build an array that looks like what you need and use `json_encode` to get it ?

Comment: @MickaëlLeger that's my approach but the foreach part I can't figure out how to do it to create the desired format. I'm having a brainfreeze

Comment: "unable to" isn't a question either. And it's barely a statement of a problem. What exactly have you tried, and what exactly goes wrong when you try it? Please clarify.

Comment: P.S. It's a bit unclear how the JSON relates to the specific data in the table...can you give a full example including the names, so we can see? The data structure you want appears a bit odd...why do you want/need it in such a format? Please explain what it's supposed to represent.

Comment: @ADyson added better example and my attempts

Comment: Ok. All you've done is create a basic array with one entry per table row. Have you actually tried to think about the structure of the data at all? You need to collect all the items of the same type, and then put them under one entry in the JSON array. Then same for all the species within that, etc all the way down your hierarchy. Or do something which assumes something of a pre-defined structure as per the answer below - it's quite a good approach I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this I think :

**1/ Fetch all your data**

```sql
SELECT tid, type, sid, species, bid, breed, vid, variety
FROM your_table
```

I will use `$your_data` as the result of your fetch (an array with multiple array, one by row in your database).

**2/ Build your array**

```php
$result = [];
foreach ($your_data as $row) {
    $result[$row['type']]['id'] = $row['tid'];
    $result[$row['type']]['species'][$row['species']]['id'] = $row['sid'];
    $result[$row['type']]['species'][$row['species']]['breeds'][$row['breed']]['id'] = $row['bid'];
    $result[$row['type']]['species'][$row['species']]['breeds'][$row['breed']]['varieties'][$row['variety']]['id'] = $row['vid'];
}
```

**3/ Now just transform your array in json :**

```php
$json = json_encode($result);
```

Here is an example with some of your data : [link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2836c3cbeb7cd3d9a775a99336b039715d8370b4)

The data I used for my example :

```php
$your_data = array(
    0 => array(
        'tid' => 1,
        'type' => 'anatidas',
        'sid' => 2,
        'species' => 'ocas',
        'bid' => 77,
        'breed' => 'emperador',
        'vid' => 118,
        'variety' => 'otro'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'tid' => 1,
        'type' => 'anatidas',
        'sid' => 2,
        'species' => 'ocas',
        'bid' => 78,
        'breed' => 'nival',
        'vid' => 118,
        'variety' => 'otro'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'tid' => 2,
        'type' => 'cobayas',
        'sid' => 14,
        'species' => 'cobaya',
        'bid' => 225,
        'breed' => 'alpaca',
        'vid' => 257,
        'variety' => 'aguti canela'       
    ),
    3 => array(
        'tid' => 2,
        'type' => 'cobayas',
        'sid' => 14,
        'species' => 'cobaya',
        'bid' => 225,
        'breed' => 'alpaca',
        'vid' => 257,
        'variety' => 'aguti dorado'       
    ),
    4 => array(
        'tid' => 2,
        'type' => 'cobayas',
        'sid' => 14,
        'species' => 'cobaya',
        'bid' => 225,
        'breed' => 'alpaca',
        'vid' => 257,
        'variety' => 'aguti gris'     
    )
);
```

**The output :**

```
{
    "anatidas": {
        "id": 1,
        "species": {
            "ocas": {
                "id": 2,
                "breeds": {
                    "emperador": {
                        "id": 77,
                        "varieties": {
                            "otro": {
                                "id": 118
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "nival": {
                        "id": 78,
                        "varieties": {
                            "otro": {
                                "id": 118
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "cobayas": {
        "id": 2,
        "species": {
            "cobaya": {
                "id": 14,
                "breeds": {
                    "alpaca": {
                        "id": 225,
                        "varieties": {
                            "aguti canela": {
                                "id": 257
                            },
                            "aguti dorado": {
                                "id": 257
                            },
                            "aguti gris": {
                                "id": 257
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect! I was thinking about loops inside the foreach, but it didn't make sense, Thanks a lot!